# Does XML support MDX Query.?

Tags: mdx

I'm doing reports using XML. Does XML support MDX Query?

Comment: What reporting environment are you using? What OLAP database?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [XMLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_for_Analysis) - "XML for analysis" for further information about this, your question is a little vague to help you further.